# IntelliJ IDEA spring template project

Tags: intellij-idea, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

In IntelliJ IDEA is there a way of creating a Spring Template Project as in Spring Source ToolSuite ? The intention over here is to get a POM file created automatically with the dependencies related to a Spring Project as in Spring Source ToolSuite. The existing way of IntelliJ IDEA is to create a Maven project and then to modify the POM file. Any information regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about intelliJ, but all of the template projects are available on giyhub.   There are URLs that aggregate the links to the template repositories.  Take a look at these two files and the clone the project that you want to use as a template:

http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/help/descriptors-3.0.xml
https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-templates/master/si-sts-templates/builds/descriptor.xml